# What should we do with this question?

Tags: discussion

[What should I do when I've been verbally told I would get an offer letter, but still haven't gotten one after 4 weeks?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10829/replying-to-job-offers)

The question is poorly formatted, but quite clear in what is being asked...yet is very much a "Which job/opportunity should i take/pursue?" question...violating the FAQ.  However, it could possibly be extrapolated to a very strong, generalized question, and it has generated a pair of fairly decent answers.  I just ding'ed and hit 2k, so I was taking a look at the close vote queue and figured I would test the waters before taking any action.

EDIT: i went through and tried to fix the question up a bit.

Comment: Don't forget the reason why "Should I take job A or job B" is off-topic is because it is a highly localized question that only the OP can answer for themselves. Often those questions are based on some key piece of information that affect the OP's decision, so you can rephrase the question to help them get the information they're missing about the deciding factor. In this case, I think the OP just wants to know what he should do when he doesn't get an official job offer letter for 3 weeks after a verbal offer, and has another offer waiting, so I rephrased the question to focus on that :)

Answer (score 7):

It is currently closed as off-topic (for the reason you've cited regarding the FAQ). If you'd like to edit it to improve the formatting, wording, and grammar, that would be a good start towards getting it reopened.

However, in order to actually reopen it, it would need to be appropriately altered to be on-topic, and still cover what the author wants to ask. For this part, I'd recommend using the comments either to help guide the author to improve it or to figure out what they want to ask and edit the question accordingly.

Comment: I have edited it up a bit to generalize the question, let me know what you think.

Comment: @acolyte - The only way I can see to make the question on topic is to remove the second offer from the question. Ask what you can do to find out the status of the original offer.

Answer (score 4):

Nice edits between everyone who edited it :)

I've voted to reopen.

Comment: As have I. Reopened.